# Is there any gain from using multiple files in SQL server for raid-5 configuration?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, sql-server-2008

We are setting up a server with five 240GB ssd as raid-5 configuration into one logical drive. We're planning to partition the logical drive into four drives on windows server.

In SQL server, would there be any advantage in setting up multiple files for a single database across the partitioned drives? I am assuming no, since even though IO is distributed across different partitions, they are grouped into a single logical drive by raid configuration.

Comment: Simple reply : yes . BUT There is a lot of solution/problems , what do you want ? Security , Io or the two ? :) There is no allin one solution but you can look at good blog like brentoza (http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/sql-server-storage-files-filegroups-video/)

Comment: Our number one concern is performance gain. What do you mean by security? Does utilizing file groups give us additional security? Also it'd be helpful if you could give me a detailed info on why there is an IO gain even though the partitioned drives are grouped into one logical drive

Comment: Its a best practice to put as many FILES in a filegroup as logical cpu you can read more details here : http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/tempdb-data-files/ and for raid5 and using ssd on sas controller there is this blog (again from brentozar sorry its just one of the best sql blog) http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/load-testing-solid-state-drives-raid/

Comment: ++ TO YuKYuK's answer. One per (logical)core, the IO threads are non-blocking so you can write/read to the files in parallel

Comment: Ok, I can see how it's beneficial to have many file groups depending on the # of logical CPUs I have. I've also read through the blog posts linked in the comments but it still doesn't answer my original question though: Are there any benefits of setting up multiple files across the partitioned drives grouped by RAID-5?

Comment: You guys are serious? 5x240.... that is around 1tb. Go Raid 1 on 2 SSD and the thing will FLY. A lot more than the pricedifference will indicate.

Comment: I would say that this wouldn't result in any benefit as the introduction of raid5 makes it more complex.  surely adding in a striped ssd would make it much faster, then you can introduce an external backup system, or mirror on the other two ssd's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no benefits to this.  It's all data to the same array through the same controller, so Windows isn't going to give you any performance benefit by doing that.

The only POSSIBLE caveat to that is if you're doing different block sizes between partitions because you have some incredibly specific reason for it.  Generally you'll want to format the disk(s) in 64k chunks, as SQL server tries to write in 64k chunks.  I can conceive of a situation in which you needed different block sizes between database drives for performance reasons, but I suspect if you were in that position you'd already know it.

tl;dr No, this won't do anything for you.

Further caveat - RAID 5 is really kinda dicey in terms of redundancy.  Disks tend to fail in clusters.  Thus you're putting yourself at higher risk of data loss by using it.  I'd go RAID 6 if you can.

Comment: Good answer. Anyway, for databases RAID10 is generally the way to go.

Comment: Not always.  Yes, RAID 10 gives you better throughput, but it's at a significant cost.  If your database doesn't need that many IOPs for performance, RAID 6 is perfectly acceptable for greater density.  Also, with RAID 10 you can lose theoretically up to half the drives in the array, but if 2 in the same stripe die, you're hosed.  With RAID 6 you can lose any 2 drives and still be okay.  RAID 10 is awesome, but it still has its caveats.